# ARKit Textures showing in XCode but objects are matte in scene

Tags: ios, xcode, 3d, arkit

I'm working with ARKit and placing some of the stock Apple objects (like the chair) in my scene; in XCode the objects preview the way I expect them, but in my scene, they don't quite look right (textures are gone).

I'm adding the chair to my scene with:

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "Models.scnassets/chair/chair.scn")
let node = scene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "chair", recursively: false)
node?.position = position
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node!)
```

The chair looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbVb1.png) in the scene editor in XCode

It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Veba1.jpg) in my scene

I'm using one of the stock models that comes with the Apple sample code, and haven't done anything to mess with the .scn file (like change textures or any material selections). Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: can you please send the link from where did you get the Apple 3D objects like chair ? because all I can find is the Space Ship only

Comment: It looks like they've changed up the code samples and don't have that one on the page anymore :( It was a downloadable example from the Apple Developer ARKit page https://developer.apple.com/arkit/

Comment: okay thanks for replying :)

Comment: I found the models on github: https://github.com/gao0122/ARKit-Example-by-Apple/tree/master/ARKitExample/Models.scnassets just in case you or anyone needed them in future :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you’re seeing is the chair model not being lit, because your new scene doesn’t have the same lighting in it that the original scene does. The original scene has a panorama image (the sort of streaky gray-yellow background in your first screenshot) set as its lighting environment; that image is where the highlights and reflections on the object are coming from. You should be able to copy the environment from one scene to the other like this:

```
sceneView.scene.lightingEnvironment.contents = scene.lightingEnvironment.contents
```

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly it.